# HTML layout for query result using dynamic variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert my query result to HTML layout. when using hardcoded tables and database i get the result, but when I use dynamic variables for database and table I am getting the error. Below is my query used. Can you please help me with the query.

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)    
Declare @DB varchar(3)    
set @DB = 'EDO'  
set @query =

cast(('SELECT DISTINCT td=SUBSTRING(LOT.KEY_FIELDS,1,15) ,'', td=SUBSTRING(LOT.KEY_FIELDS,16,15),'',
td=SUBSTRING(LOT.SUN_DATA,1,8) ,'',SUBSTRING(LOT.SUN_DATA,9,40) ,''
FROM SSRFMSC LOT LEFT OUTER JOIN SMMFMOV'+@DB+' INV ON SUBSTRING(LOT.KEY_FIELDS,16,15) = INV.RECPT_REF AND 
SUBSTRING(LOT.KEY_FIELDS,1,15) = INV.ITEM_CODE 
WHERE 
INV.ITEM_CODE IS NULL 
AND 
LOT.SUN_DB =''' +@DB+ '''  AND LOT.SUN_TB = ''MIV'' 
and SUBSTRING(LOT.SUN_DATA,1,8) > (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS [YYYYMMDD]) ')  
for xml path('tr'),type) as nvarchar(max))+N'< /table>'
select @query
```

"Unable to add HTML layout"

Comment: This isn't [tag:mysql]; fixed tag.

Comment: Why are you appending `< /table>` to your dynamic SQL query?

Comment: You'd be much more efficient just fetching the data and transform it to HTML in your web server code instead.

Comment: After set @query= there are a set of HTML codes for the layout but I couldn't include them in the above

Comment: Crono1981 can you please tell me how?